# Add lateral facets to a dotplot with multiple values for variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

i have this table:

```
fruit   value   feature Ratio   Category
tomato  1.79614067223751    length  0.00983606557377    A
zucchini    3.03886853214095    size    0.034188034188034   A
tomato  1.64545172419968    size    0.013114754098361   A
potato  4.25443807208955    size    0.008383233532934   A
zucchini    5   colour  0.051282051282051   B
potato  1.46068422675856    magic   0.004790419161677   B
potato  5   flavour 0.011377245508982   B
tomato  4.86348870541553    flavour 0.026229508196721   B
zucchini    2.89808116631958    flavour 0.034188034188034   B
```

i would like to modify this dotplot in order to group the "feature" with the facet_grid function by Category A and B.

```
test <- read.delim("test.txt")

p1 <- ggplot(data = test,
             aes(x = fruit, y = feature)) +
    geom_point(aes(size = Ratio, 
                   color = value,
                   fill = value), 
               stroke = 0.5,
               shape = 21) +
    guides(color = FALSE) +
    scale_fill_viridis_c()
```

i've checked this post https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-use-label-parsed-when-combining-multi-level-facets-in-ggplot2/29600 but i couldn't find a way to apply this to my case.

[image]

```
> dput(test)
structure(list(fruit = structure(c(2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 3L), .Label = c("potato", "tomato", "zucchini"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(1.79614067223751, 3.03886853214095, 1.64545172419968, 
    4.25443807208955, 5, 1.46068422675856, 5, 4.86348870541553, 
    2.89808116631958), feature = structure(c(3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("colour", "flavour", "length", 
    "magic", "size"), class = "factor"), Ratio = c(0.00983606557377, 
    0.034188034188034, 0.013114754098361, 0.008383233532934, 
    0.051282051282051, 0.004790419161677, 0.011377245508982, 
    0.026229508196721, 0.034188034188034), Category = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Comment: Isn't it just `+ facet_wrap(~ Category)` or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's just `+ facet_wrap(~ Category)` as @Rui Barradas said or `+ facet_wrap(Category~.)` to have the features divided

Comment: dear @RuiBarradas and JaiPizGon thank you but i just want to group the "feature" by category and NOT the "fruit"  and i don't want repetition of the features in the panels A and B

Comment: Please post the output of `dput(test)` in the question.

Comment: @RuiBarradas done

Answer (score 2):

Add `facet_wrap(~Category, scales = "free_y", ncol = 1)` to your plot.

[image]

Or you may prefer adding `facet_grid(Category ~ ., scales = "free_y", space = "free_y")`